# Code not working trying to write the content of a StringVar to a file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a lot of experience with basic programming, but none with GUI programming, and I am teaching myself Python 3 with tkinter for that purpose.  I've got some great answers by checking stackoverflow posts, but now I've got a problem that doesn't seem to have been covered.  I want my program to get user input from an Entry widget and write that data to a file.  After stripping out all nonessential lines, my current code is

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

sheetid = StringVar()

def finish():
    with open('C:/Python33/data.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('first line of text\n')
    with open('C:/Python33/data.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(sheetid)

main = Frame(root).grid()
ttk.Entry(main, textvariable="sheetid").grid(row=0, column=1)
ttk.Button(main, text="Close", command=finish).grid(column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I've previously used the Label widget to write the variable "sheetid"in a window, so I know the combination of Entry widget and the "Close" Button widget are working.  The first write statement works, so I know my file-opening code is correct.  The second write gives a run-time error:

TypeError: must be str, not StringVar.

Next I tried converting "sheetid" to a string, using

```
s = str(sheetid,'\n')
```

but this also returned a run-time error:

TypeError: coercing to str: need bytes, bytearray or buffer-like object, StringVar found.

Surely there is a way to do this, but my google search hasn't found it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `..., textvariable="sheetid"`, you must use `..., textvariable=sheetid, ...` (notice the lack of quotes around `sheetid`). And then, when you want to write the value out you must use `sheetid.get()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Bryan.  This did fix the problem.  I didn't think the quotation marks made any sense.  The problem is that I had to add them to fix an earlier problem which I had omitted from the code in this post.  Here is a stripped down version of that problem:

Comment: Sorry--I messed up the box.  In my other code, two variables got set in Entry widgets in one window.  The "Close" button in that window opens a new window that contains those variables in Label widgets.  Without the quotations marks, they don't get copied correctly in the new window.

Comment: @GlennLedder: I don't quite understand what you wrote, but trust me, using quotes for the textvariable isn't the right way to use textvariables. The value for the `textvariable` attribute must be an instance of one of the Tkinter variable classes.